# Multiple arrays, checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html

What I want to try to do is kind of tricky so I will list the steps and my code below.

1. When the page opens the user is presented two options via checkboxes.  On load neither are defaulted as checked.  If the user checks the top one and decides they dont want that one the other should be cleared.
2. Whatever ends up being selected and they press Submit, I would like that array to populate the screen.  Right now its just dummy names but will change.  If after loading the array and they want to change to the other check box, the array on the screen needs to be cleared and the other one loaded with breaks between them.  That holds true for either one they choose.

Ive posted my code so far below.  The html renders correctly.  What I dont know how to do is load the arrays.  Just learning JS but this was presented to me to get done.

```js
<script>
var cash = ["Susan", "Billy", "Jennifer"];
document.write(cash[0]);
var cust = ["David", "Larry", "Melissa"];
document.write(cust[0]);
</script>
```

```html
<DOCTYPE = html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1 {
  color: blue;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 100%;
}
label {
  color: blue;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<center>
<p><img src="C:\Users\hac532\Desktop\Logos\CO-BT.JPG" alt="CO Logo" style="width:231px;height:212px;margin-left:15px;">
<h1>Select the department you want comments for from the list below by checking the box next to it</h1>
<br>
<br>
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="checkbox" id="Cash Applications" name="Cash Applications" value="Cash Apps">
  <label for="Cash Applications"> Cash Applications</label><br>
<br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="Customer Service" name="Customer Service" value="Customer Service">
  <label for="vehicle2"> Customer Service</label><br>
<br>
 <br>
<br>
 <input type="submit" value="Select">
<button type="Clear Selection" id="button1" >Clear</button>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question feels very broad. Are you asking how to use JS to add something onto an already-loaded page? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

So, your current scripts just directly append with document.writes.  You need to define some elements to hold the info you want to display/update.  I defined a div named "displaySelected".  It starts out empty.

To handle the toggle of checkboxes you need some onclick functions for each checkbox... I defined a single one named selectBox and passed in a string to tell the function which checkbox was checked.  In that function if cash was clicked then I clear cust and if cust was checked then I clear cash.

To handle displaying the selection you need an onclick function for the submit button.  I created one named selectArray().  It clears out the contents of the displaySelected div and then creates an unordered list element then loops through whichever array was selected and creates list item elements and populates their text with the item from the array.  Use the appendChild() function to add the li to the ul and the ul to the div

To handle clearing the selection you need an onclick function for the clear button.  I created one named clearSelection().  It unchecks both boxes and then clears out the contents of the displaySelected div by setting its innerHTML to ''

```js
var cash = ["Susan", "Billy", "Jennifer"];
var cust = ["David", "Larry", "Melissa"];

var cashBox = document.getElementById("Cash Applications");
var custBox = document.getElementById("Customer Service");
var displayDiv = document.getElementById("displaySelected");

function selectBox(box) {
  switch (box) {
    case 'cash':
      custBox.checked = false;
      break;
    case 'cust':
      cashBox.checked = false;
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}

function selectArray() {
  displayDiv.innerHTML = '';
  var uList = document.createElement("ul");
  if (cashBox.checked) {
    for (var cashIndex = 0; cashIndex < cash.length; cashIndex++) {
      var cashEle = document.createElement("li");
      cashEle.innerText = cash[cashIndex];
      uList.appendChild(cashEle);
    }
  } else if (custBox.checked) {
    for (var custIndex = 0; custIndex < cust.length; custIndex++) {
      var custEle = document.createElement("li");
      custEle.innerText = cust[custIndex];
      uList.appendChild(custEle);
    }
  }
  displayDiv.appendChild(uList);
}

function clearSelection() {
  cashBox.checked = false;
  custBox.checked = false;
  displayDiv.innerHTML = '';
}
```

```css
h1 {
  color: blue;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 100%;
}

label {
  color: blue;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <center>
    <img src="C:\Users\hac532\Desktop\Logos\CO-BT.JPG" alt="CO Logo" style="width:231px;height:212px;margin-left:15px;">
    <h1>Select the department you want comments for from the list below by checking the box next to it</h1>
    <br>
    <br>
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <input type="checkbox" id="Cash Applications" name="Cash Applications" value="Cash Apps" onclick="selectBox('cash')">
      <label for="Cash Applications"> Cash Applications</label><br>
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="Customer Service" name="Customer Service" value="Customer Service" onclick="selectBox('cust')">
      <label for="vehicle2"> Customer Service</label><br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Select" onclick="selectArray()">
      <button type="Clear Selection" id="button1" onclick="clearSelection()">Clear</button>
    </form>
    <br><br>
    <div id="displaySelected">
    </div>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for contributing.  i will try them all out.

Comment: I like them all radio buttons or check buttons are ok not the most important.  A couple things:  kmosers solution throws a syntax error if you run the code snippet line 77:  "https://stacksnippets.net/js"  but I dont see it it the code.  Dynastics runs error free and displays the array chosen for a second or 2 then the whole screen is cleared.  I need the header check boxes to stay at all times and just the array change depending on the checkbox/radio button chosen.   Thanks for everyones help i couldnt have gotten this far this quickly.  Is it better to put the functions in a separate file?

Comment: still trying to get the hang of responding.  anyway i tidied up my html to include the css and js.  the css works fine.  the js file is at the end of the body and looks like this:  <script src="main.js"></script>.  Its in the root directory along with the html.  when trying to interact with the form, its as if the .js file doesnt work because when you click the submit button you get file not found.  Tried a few different things but none seem to work.

Comment: after some trouble shooting it appears to be a chrome issue.  it will not load javascript to localhost although the settings are on for javascript.  Probably the reason it works when I run the script snippet you posted from the site is i guess stack overflow has a server it runs on.  Im just trying to run this on my pc.  I think I read a resolution on here somewhere but im not sure.  So if anyone knows of a way to get the script to run on localhost it would be good tp know.  I used chrome developer tools to see where it failed.

Answer (score 0):

This is not as elaborate as the previous answer, but it still works.

```
<DOCTYPE = html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1 {
  color: blue;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 100%;
}
label {
  color: blue;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
</style>
</head>

<script>
var cash = ["Susan", "Billy", "Jennifer"];
document.write(cash[0]);
var cust = ["David", "Larry", "Melissa"];
document.write(cust[0]);

function doChkClick(e) {
    //get references to elements
    spn = document.getElementById('spnout');
    chkcash = document.getElementById('chkCash');
    chkcust = document.getElementById('chkCust');
    
    // reverse other checkbox
    if (e === chkcash && e.checked) chkcust.checked = false
    if (e === chkcust && e.checked) chkcash.checked = false
    
    // show array
    if (chkcash.checked) spn.innerHTML = cash.join(' ')
    if (chkcust.checked) spn.innerHTML = cust.join(' ')
    
    // if nothing checked
    if (!chkcash.checked && !chkcust.checked)
        spn.innerHTML = '[Empty]'
}
</script>

<body>
<center>
<p><img src="C:\Users\hac532\Desktop\Logos\CO-BT.JPG" alt="CO Logo" style="width:231px;height:212px;margin-left:15px;">
<h1>Select the department you want comments for from the list below by checking the box next to it</h1>
<br>
<br>
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="checkbox" name="Cash Applications" value="Cash Apps" id="chkCash" onclick=doChkClick(this)>
  <label for="Cash Applications"> Cash Applications</label><br>
<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Customer Service" value="Customer Service" id="chkCust" onclick=doChkClick(this)>
  <label for="vehicle2"> Customer Service</label><br>
<br>
<br>
<b><span id="spnout">[Empty]</span></b>
<br>
<br>
 <input type="submit" value="Select">
 <button type="Clear Selection" id="button1" >Clear</button>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

If you prefer to have the script separate from the html, you can use these files:

main.js

```
var cash = ["Susan", "Billy", "Jennifer"];
document.write(cash[0]);
var cust = ["David", "Larry", "Melissa"];
document.write(cust[0]);

function doChkClick(e) {
    //get references to elements
    spn = document.getElementById('spnout');
    chkcash = document.getElementById('chkCash');
    chkcust = document.getElementById('chkCust');
    
    // reverse other checkbox
    if (e === chkcash && e.checked) chkcust.checked = false
    if (e === chkcust && e.checked) chkcash.checked = false
    
    // show array
    if (chkcash.checked) spn.innerHTML = cash.join(' ')
    if (chkcust.checked) spn.innerHTML = cust.join(' ')
    
    // if nothing checked
    if (!chkcash.checked && !chkcust.checked)
        spn.innerHTML = '[Empty]'
}
```

main.htm

```
<DOCTYPE = html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1 {
  color: blue;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 100%;
}
label {
  color: blue;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
</style>

<script src="main.js"></script> 

</head>

<body>
<center>
<p><img src="C:\Users\hac532\Desktop\Logos\CO-BT.JPG" alt="CO Logo" style="width:231px;height:212px;margin-left:15px;">
<h1>Select the department you want comments for from the list below by checking the box next to it</h1>
<br>
<br>
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="checkbox" name="Cash Applications" value="Cash Apps" id="chkCash" onclick=doChkClick(this)>
  <label for="Cash Applications"> Cash Applications</label><br>
<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Customer Service" value="Customer Service" id="chkCust" onclick=doChkClick(this)>
  <label for="vehicle2"> Customer Service</label><br>
<br>
<br>
<b><span id="spnout">[Empty]</span></b>
<br>
<br>
 <input type="submit" value="Select">
 <button type="Clear Selection" id="button1" >Clear</button>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I like them all radio buttons or check buttons are ok not the most important.

Comment: I tided up my html a bit but having trouble with the javascript which is its own file in the root folder.  I put this line below right below the </body> tag but when you want to interact with the .js file via the text boxes i get "file not found"

Comment: <script src="main.js"></script>

Comment: Answer updated. I usually put the script reference in the head to ensure it is loaded early.

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes usually let the user select more than one. Your restriction of only allowing one to be selected is kind of nonstandard so I've changed them to radio buttons.

You've also got an `action` on your form, which will cause it to load another page. I added an `onclick` handler which stops it from submitting.

```js
var cash = ["Susan", "Billy", "Jennifer"];
//document.write(cash[0]);
var cust = ["David", "Larry", "Melissa"];
//document.write(cust[0]);

function do_submit() {
    // Decide which list to use:

    var list = null;
    if ( document.getElementById('Cash Applications').checked ) {
        list = cash;
    }
    if ( document.getElementById('Customer Service').checked ) {
        list = cust;
    }

    if ( list == null ) {
        alert( 'Please select a list.' );
    } else {
        Put the list items on the page in the 'list' div:

        let listElement = document.getElementById( 'list' );
        listElement.innerHTML = '';
        list.forEach( function( name ) {
            listElement.innerHTML += name + '<br>';
        });
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE = html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1 {
  color: blue;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 100%;
}
label {
  color: blue;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<center>
<p><img src="C:\Users\hac532\Desktop\Logos\CO-BT.JPG" alt="CO Logo" style="width:231px;height:212px;margin-left:15px;">
<h1>Select the department you want comments for from the list below by checking the box next to it</h1>
<br>
<br>
<form action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return do_submit();">
  <input type="radio" id="Cash Applications" name="name" value="Cash Apps">
  <label for="CashApplications"> Cash Applications</label><br>
<br>
  <input type="radio" id="Customer Service" name="name" value="Customer Service">
  <label for="Customer Service"> Customer Service</label><br>
<br>
 <br>
<br>
 <input type="submit" value="Select">
<button type="Clear Selection" id="button1" >Clear</button>
</center>

<div id="list">names will appear here</div>

</body>
</html>
```